# Google IMPORTXML scraping Shopee price to google sheet

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets

I am trying to pull price from this URL:
https://shopee.co.th/product-i.389528981.8764867001

So I use this path:

```
=importXML"https://shopee.co.th/product-i.389528981.8764867001","[//div[contains@class,'_3e_UQT')]")
```

But still it doesn't work, anyone please give me advice.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets does not support web scraping of JavaScript-controlled elements. you can easily check it by disabling JS for a given site and only what's left visible can be scraped. in your case, that's nothing, unfortunately:

[image]

Comment: you're right! sometimes we can find an url or a json in a script (eg yahoo) in the source code, this is not the case here !

Comment: @MikeSteelson go for it - reopened

Comment: It's a challenge ... the json is normally contained here `xhr.open("GET",origin+"/api/v4/pages/is_short_url/?path="+pathname.replace("/",""))` with origin = `https://shopee.co.th` and pathname = `/product-i.389528981.8764867001` , but if you call directly this url the answer is an empty json; I will try later by adding `xhr.setRequestHeader`

Comment: No way on my side, I did some tests with ajax and XMLHttpRequest but the json remains empty!